# Use of Uhlmann representation in proving the strong subadditivity of the von Neumann entropy

Tags: quantum-information, entropy, density-operator

I am trying to prove strong subadditivity of the von Neumann-entropy, using joint convexity of the quantum relative entropy.
The procedure is given in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_subadditivity_of_quantum_entropy.
However, I do not have access to the cited paper by Uhlmann on "Endlich Dimensionale Dichtematrizen II (1973)".

In the wikipedia article, 
$$
\text{tr}_B(\rho_{AB} ) = N^{-1} \sum_{j=1}^N (1_{A}\otimes U_j) \rho_{AB}(1_{A}\otimes U_j^\dagger)
$$
for some unitaries $\{U_j\}$, is given as "the Uhlmann representation" of the partial trace.

I am not familiar with this representation and I would argue that the partial trace cannot be expressed via unitaries, since it maps into a smaller space.

How do I have to understand this decomposition to be able to continue with the proof?

- Note:
  I tried approaching the problem via the Kraus decomposition
  $$
  \text{tr}_B: \rho_{AB}\mapsto\sum_{j=1}^N (1_A \otimes \langle j|_B)\ \rho_{AB}\ (1_A\otimes|j\rangle_B).
  $$
  Since the next step relies on unitary invariance of the quantum relative entropy, this does not seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the Wikipedia article, I would assume what is meant is 
$$
\text{tr}_B(\rho_{AB} )\otimes 1\!\!1 = N^{-1} \sum_{j=1}^N (1_{A}\otimes U_j) \rho_{AB}(1_{A}\otimes U_j^\dagger)\ ,
$$
in particular since it is suggested that one can take a Haar integral instead (which definitely gives the above formula). The l.h.s. can the in some sense be considered as "equivalent" to $\mathrm{tr}_B(\rho_{AB})$.